# JQuery UI Autocomplete returning all values

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following code:

$("#auto").autocomplete({
  source: "js/search.php",
  minLength: "3" });

This code is assign to an input text box where i type a name and after 3 letters it should return the ones that have similar letters. For my case it is returning all values, even those not related to the 3 letters already typed. My question is:

How to send my search.php file the value inside the input so it should know what to search for. For the moment it searches for everything. I checked the value that was going to php and it was empty. Since the query to mysql uses LIKE '%VARIABLE%' and the variable is empty it searches for '%%' which is all cases.

How can i send the correct informacion from JS to PHP with the simplest form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the explanation :
http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-a-remote-database-and-php/

Regards